# How to deal with conflicts in parsing dates in multiple formats through parse_date_time in lubridate

Tags: r, parsing, lubridate

I just referred [help page](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/parse_date_time.html) of `lubridate::parse_date_time()` especially for its `select_format` argument. But I am not able to get it and design my own function for my own use case.

Actually, I have a vector of uncleaned dates in a few formats.  For sake of simplicity, let us suppose, I have dates in `mdy`, `dmy`, `ymd` and `ydm` formats.

```r
my_dates <- c("1988-02-03", "1988-15-03", "05-12-2023", "5-27-2022")

lubridate::parse_date_time(my_dates, orders = c("dmy","mdy", "ymd", 'ydm'))

#> [1] "1988-03-02 UTC" "1988-03-15 UTC" "2023-05-12 UTC" "2022-05-27 UTC"
```

In output I want `dmy` precedence over `mdy` and `ymd` having precedence over `ydm`.  How can I do it?  My output should be-

```
#> [1] "1988-02-03 UTC" "1988-03-15 UTC" "2023-12-05 UTC" "2022-05-27 UTC"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parse_date_time()` by default generates a set of `strptime()` date formats (e.g. `%Y-%m-%d`) based on the `orders` supplied, trains these against a subset of the dates and these formats are ranked by the number of matches against the training data with weights applied based on the number of tokens in the format and the presence of certain tokens.

To use the formats guessed from `orders` in sequence, you can set `train = FALSE`.

```
library(lubridate)

my_dates <- c("1988-02-03", "1988-15-03", "05-12-2023", "5-27-2022")
my_orders <- c("dmy","mdy", "ymd", 'ydm')

parse_date_time(my_dates, my_orders, train = FALSE)
[1] "1988-02-03 UTC" "1988-03-15 UTC" "2023-12-05 UTC" "2022-05-27 UTC"
```

If you wanted to use the `select_format` argument as intended, it might be useful to step through what is happening. The documentation states the argument takes

> a function to select actual formats for parsing from a set of formats
> which matched a training subset of x.  It receives a named integer
> vector and returns a character vector of selected formats. Names of
> the input vector are formats (not orders) that matched the training
> set.

We can see the formats guessed by calling `guess_formats()`:

```
(guesses <- guess_formats(my_dates, my_orders))

       dOmy        Omdy        Omdy        yOmd        ydOm        ydOm         dmy         mdy         mdy         ymd         ydm 
"%d-%Om-%Y" "%Om-%d-%Y" "%Om-%d-%Y" "%Y-%Om-%d" "%Y-%d-%Om" "%Y-%d-%Om"  "%d-%m-%Y"  "%m-%d-%Y"  "%m-%d-%Y"  "%Y-%m-%d"  "%Y-%d-%m" 
        ydm 
 "%Y-%d-%m"
```

As the same format can be guessed multiple times only the unique formats are needed:

```
guesses <- unique(guesses)
```

These are tested against the training set to see how many valid conversions each format returns:

```
lubridate:::.train_formats(my_dates, guesses, "")

%Om-%d-%Y %Y-%d-%Om  %m-%d-%Y  %Y-%d-%m %d-%Om-%Y %Y-%Om-%d  %d-%m-%Y  %Y-%m-%d 
        2         2         2         2         1         1         1         1
```

By default, this named vector is then passed to the `.select_formats` function that weights and then orders the formats.  You can inspect the unexported function to see the default weights applied to certain tokens:

```
lubridate:::.select_formats
function (trained, drop = FALSE) 
{
    nms <- names(trained)
    score <- nchar(gsub("[^%]", "", nms)) + grepl("%Y", nms, 
        fixed = T) * 1.5 + grepl("%y(?!%)", nms, perl = T) * 
        1.6 + grepl("%[Bb]", nms) * 0.31 + grepl("%Om", nms) * 
        0.3 + grepl("%Op", nms) * 0.3 + grepl("%Ob", nms) * 0.32
    n0 <- trained != 0
    if (drop) {
        score <- score[n0]
        trained <- trained[n0]
    }
    else {
        score[!n0] <- -100
    }
    names(trained)[order(score, trained, decreasing = T)]
}
```

The default priority of formats when you call `parse_date_time(my_dates, my_orders)` is:

```
lubridate:::.select_formats(lubridate:::.train_formats(my_dates, guesses, locale = ""))
[1] "%Om-%d-%Y" "%Y-%d-%Om" "%d-%Om-%Y" "%Y-%Om-%d" "%m-%d-%Y"  "%Y-%d-%m"  "%d-%m-%Y"  "%Y-%m-%d"
```

To change this we can supply a custom function to apply different weights, namely prioritising formats that start with `%d-%m` over `%m-%d` and `%Y-%m` over `%Y-%d`.

```
my_select <- function(trained) {
  nms <- names(trained)
  score <- nchar(gsub("[^%]", "", nms)) + grepl("^%d-%O?m", nms) * 2 + grepl("^%Y-%O?m", nms) * 2
  nms[order(score, trained, decreasing = TRUE)]
}
```

Using this, the priority is now:

```
my_select(lubridate:::.train_formats(my_dates, guesses, locale = ""))
[1] "%d-%Om-%Y" "%Y-%Om-%d" "%d-%m-%Y"  "%Y-%m-%d"  "%Om-%d-%Y" "%Y-%d-%Om" "%m-%d-%Y"  "%Y-%d-%m"
```

And if we use it in `parse_date_time()` we get your desired result:

```
parse_date_time(my_dates, orders, select_formats = my_select)
[1] "1988-02-03 UTC" "1988-03-15 UTC" "2023-12-05 UTC" "2022-05-27 UTC"
```

It's worth noting another alternative is use `parse_date_time2` and pass `strptime` formats directly to `orders`:

```
parse_date_time2(my_dates, orders = c("%d-%m-%Y","%m-%d-%Y", "%Y-%m-%d", '%Y-%d-%m'))
[1] "1988-02-03 UTC" "1988-03-15 UTC" "2023-12-05 UTC" "2022-05-27 UTC"
```

Comment: Thanks for excellent information.  I am accepting this one.